# How can I know if a game is being played in my area (where I live)?

Tags: steam, rainbow-six-siege

I keep hesitating in buying some games on Steam for not knowing if there are active servers or players on that game where I live. I live in Afghanistan, that's probably Central Asia. I can play CSGO with an Ok ping (135 -160) with an Ok internet (net is damn expensive here unfortunately).  I used to play "Dayz" while I was in Malaysia, but here I can't even find a single player or a server nearby with low ping in Dayz. So this is what got me worried about the other games, specifically:

1) Squad

2) Rainbow Six Siege

3) Arma 3

Comment: Such thing would probably never exist, since people enjoy their privacy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, the overall player based numbers had been published (avg, peak, downloads) but currently there is no reference to how the numbers look per region.

Your best bet is to discuss with people playing the game from your country and see the servers, count and ping (or read the reviews in your language at the bottom of the game page). Also, the servers are different based upon the game, Rainbow Six Siege for example has the following:

; eus 'us east'
; cus 'us central'
; scus 'us south central'
; wus 'us west'
; sbr 'brazil south'
; neu 'europe north'
; weu 'europe west'
; eas 'asia east'
; seas 'asia south east'
; eau 'australia east'
; wja 'japan west'